# jqgrid, how to POST fields before delete row

Tags: jqgrid

I need to know how to send fields before a delete in jqgrid, to add is easy I have a script for that, but for delete I can't.

here a example to add:

```
{//add
recreateForm:true,
jqModal:true,
reloadAfterSubmit:true,
savekey: [true,13],
closeOnEscape:true,
closeAfterAdd:true,
height:150,
width:450,
url:"process/jqgridAnaOT.php",
addCaption : "Asigancion de Analista",
      beforeSubmit:function(postdata){
                var dataString = $("#formid").serialize();
                var numReg = document.getElementById('OT').value; 
                var assign = document.getElementById('Siglas').value;
                var txt_open = document.getElementById('txt_open2').value;
 if(txt_open==0){
          jAlert('La orden se encuentra cerrada, No es posible modificar datos',titulo);
                return false;  
    } else { ...

      }   },
```

as you see, to add we have a form which we are able to manipulate the data in,
the function beforeSubmit allows us know data in the form, but when we delete a row it does not exist in the form if not a message from jqgrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/how-to-send-additional-post-data-when-deleting-a-row#p17185

```
        $(function(){
             $("#list").jqGrid({
                   colNames:[...],
                   colModel :[...],
                etc...
               });
         $("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
        {add:true,edit:false,del:true,search:false,refresh:true},
        {//edit},
        {//add},
        {//del
          code....
        }
        );
        });
```

In this method i use the interface by default for jqgrid it most clearly to use, using the solution i adapted my code and it work's fine.

```
{//del
recreateForm:true,
jqModal:true,
reloadAfterSubmit:true,
savekey: [true,13],
closeOnEscape:true,
closeAfterAdd:true,
height:130,
width:450,
url:'process/jqgridAnaOT.php?pid="<?=$strPid?>"',
onclickSubmit: function(params){
var txt_open = document.getElementById('txt_open2').value;
var gr = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
var val = jQuery('#list').jqGrid('getCell',gr,'Siglas');                                        
    if(txt_open==0){
    jAlert('La orden se encuentra cerrada, No es posible modificar datos',titulo);
    return false;  
     }
     else {
           return {Siglas:val};
          }
  } 
}  // fin del
```

I hope this code has usefull for somebody

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar event when you  delete the row. If you use Guriddo jqGrid you may want to look at the [documentation here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/editing/#del-grid-row)